# Awk sum csv columns based on fields

Tags: bash, awk, join

I have N files like so:

file1.txt

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5
A,B,RANDOM,1,2
C,D,RANDOM,3,4
```

fileN.txt

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5
A,B,RANDOM,1,2
C,D,RANDOM,3,4
```

They all have the same headers. I would like to sum all of Header4 and Header5 based on Header1 and Header2. So all items with the `A,B` fields should sum Header4,Header5.

To print something like

```
A,B,2,4
C,D,6,8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming ordering of output is no requirement...

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP="," }
  { s4[$1,$2]+=$4 ; s5[$1,$2]+=$5 }
  END { for (k in s4) print k,s4[k],s5[k] }
' file1 ... fileN
```

(Edited and restructured for better legibility.)

Comment: What happens when not all files have `A,B`? Also would it be possible to print the number of times `A,B` was found?

Comment: @StenKin, what do you mean? This solution does not rely on "A" or "B". Do you mean that some files do not have 5 columns? Or that some fields are empty?

Comment: @Sten Kin, in this case there's nothing to add for those files and only the other files contribute to the key "A,B". In other words, the code is robust against inhomogeneous data files of that sort.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Neat solution.

Comment: @Sten Kin, I see you had another question in your comment (but not in your original question above). To get the number of appearences of the keys you can count them, `c[$1,$2]++`, and print thes result (e.g. by adding `c[k]` as another argument in the print statement).